# How do I run my shell scripts in EC2?

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have set of shell scripts that I wish to run in my ec2 instance.. I tried this

```
ec2-run-instances -K testing2.pem ami-****** -d Setup.sh
```

I get an error like this  :

```
Required option '-C, --cert CERT' missing (-h for usage)
```

What is wrong in the above commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `EC2_CERT` environment variable, and based on the fact that you've called your key `testing2.pem`, I'd hypothesize you're also missing `EC2_PRIVATE_KEY`. [From the setup instructions:](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/setting-up-your-tools.html#set-aws-credentials)

> Because you can have more than one AWS account, you need to identify yourself so that the command line tools know which credentials to use. It's possible, but tedious, to provide this information as a command line option every time you invoke each command. So we recommend that you set up these environment variables and be done with it.
>
> There are two environment variables you can set to point at your private key and certificate. After you set these environment variables, the tools use their values to find your credentials. The environment variable EC2_PRIVATE_KEY should point to your private key file, and EC2_CERT should point to your X.509 certificate.

When you've set up those environment variables, you'll be able to use them for all AWS CLI tools.

Assuming `testing2.pem` is an instance keypair, what you really want is this command, after you've set up those environment variables, of course. Note the lowercase `-k` flag:

```
ec2-run-instances ami-****** -k testing2.pem -d Setup.sh
```